# QSqlDatabase delete all rows from table

Tags: mysql, qt, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase

Hi I need  to delete all rows from QSqlDatabase table, my code looks,

```
      QString dbName = QDir::currentPath()+"/DB";
      QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
      db.setDatabaseName(dbName);
      if(db.open()){
        QSqlQuery query(db);
        query.prepare("truncate fRecogtable"); // this not working
        //query.prepare("Delete from fRecogtable"); //this working

        if(!query.exec() )
          qDebug() << "deletion failed";
        query.clear();
        db.close();
        }
```

The issue is the command `truncate fRecogtable` not deleting the record from table where as `Delete from fRecogtable` working. I need to use  `truncate` as  I have to reset auto incremental fields.

What can be the issue?

**Edit:**

Finally I manged to get work with

```
query.prepare("Delete from fRecogtable");
 if(!query.exec() )
    qDebug() << "deletion failed";

 query.clear();
 query.prepare("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name='fRecogtable'");
 if(!query.exec() )
     qDebug() << "deletion failed";
```

Thanks
Haris

Comment: just do a `truncate table fRecogtable`

Comment: I tried that too but it's also not working.

Comment: ```` query.exec("DELETE FROM table_name") ````    worked but    ```` query.exec("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name='table_name'") ```` didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In PyQt this problem solves with `query.exec_('TRUNCATE my_table;')`, you don't need `prepare()`.